# Twitch TV OAuth Login In C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, justin.tv

I am trying to connect a twitch TV account to a user profile on my website and I am getting a 403 Forbidden error.  I am trying to use the Authorization Code Flow specified here: https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/authentication.md#auth-code but the 2nd part where I have to Post back to Twitch TV is where I am getting the error.  I am doing this with ASP.net MVC3 and C#.

Here is my method to get the code and ask the user to give my application access to twitch TV (This works as expected):

```
  [Authorize]
  public ActionResult TwitchTvLogOn(string returnUrl)
  {
     string redirectUrl = "";

     // This is special code used to determine the URL that will be used when working in UGDB since the URL is different in 
     // development than it is in production.
     #if (DEBUG)
        redirectUrl = "http://localhost:58386/Account/AuthorizeTwitchTv";
     #else
        redirectUrl = "http://www.mywebsite.com/Account/AuthorizeTwitchTv";
     #endif

     var loginUri = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=" +
                    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitchClientId"] +
                    "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUrl + "&state=" + returnUrl;

     return Redirect(loginUri);
  }
```

This is the part that is not working correctly and is giving the 403:

```
  public ActionResult AuthorizeTwitchTv(string code, string state)
  {
     string currentUrl = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
              string redirectUrl = "";

     #if (DEBUG)
        redirectUrl = "http://localhost:58386/Account/AuthorizeTwitchTv";
     #else
        redirectUrl = "http://www.mywebsite.com/Account/AuthorizeTwitchTv";
     #endif

     var twitchTvPost = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/token?client_id=" +
                             System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitchClientId"] + "&client_secret=" +
                             System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitchAppSecret"] + "&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=" + 
                             redirectUrl + "&code=" + code;

     ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
     string postData = "client_id=" + System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitchClientId"];
     postData += ("&client_secret=" + System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitchAppSecret"]);
     postData += ("&grant_type=authorization_code");
     postData += ("&redirect_uri=" + redirectUrl);
     postData += ("&code=" + code);
     byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

     // Prepare POST web request...
     HttpWebRequest myRequest =
       (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/token"));
     myRequest.Method = "POST";
     myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
     myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
     Stream newStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream();
     // Send the data.
     newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
     newStream.Close();

     // Get response  
     HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
     // Get the response stream  
     StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

     // Read the whole contents and return as a string  
     string result = reader.ReadToEnd();


     return View();
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  The overall end goal is to get the "access_token" so I can use it to get the current user's twitch username and be able to grab that user's channels and feeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not very good with this, but i think the problem is that you are trying to connect to localhost wich is your own computer trough a server port. if this is not the problem and this is what you want. did you think about port forwarding?

Comment: Actually that makes some sense I will see if I can get it to work with that in mind. Thanks!

Comment: Ok with that in mind and looking at my code I found that I had extra = signs in a couple places and that my secret and id were for production rather than for localhost.